# Varying emitter base voltage of a BJT in LTspice

Tags: bjt, ltspice

I am doing an assignment which has asked me to find the effect of varying \$V_{EB}\$ on paramaters such as voltage gain , current gain and input resistance for the following circuit :
[image]

I attempted this question by hooking up a voltage source like this :
[image]

But when i run the circuit , it shows "Failed to find DC Operating Point for AC analysis" .

Why it's showing such an error and how do i get to plot \$V_{EB}\$ along the x-axis ?

Comment: Do you *have* to use this specific circuit? You may change Vbe @ DC operating point by changing any of the resistors or V2, but this would *also* change Ib, Ic and Vce, so you would not be evaluating the change in Vbe exclusively.

Comment: @Starboy: What would happen in reality if you connected a battery to the base and emitter as you have V3 connected?

Comment: @JRE It would burn the circuit due to a high value of current  without a resistance in place ?

Comment: Right.  What ever you are trying to do, destroying transistors won't get you there.

Comment: @Starboy It's called sensitivity analysis, I think. Once you understand the idea, it's really easy to apply. You don't need Spice for this. It's pure math.

Comment: You can parameterize R1 then get LTspice to plot a series of curves with R1 being different values.

Answer (score 1):

For the x-axis, select the waveform window, hover the mouse over the X-axis until the cursor changes into a ruler, then `RClick` on it and change `time` to `V(Ve,Vb)`, or `V(Ve)-V(Vb)` (same thing). It may not work since you seem to have assigned two labels to the same node. LTspice will take precedence to the last assigned name (except for the ground).

For changing the BE voltage, you'll have to either change the parameters of the transistor `.model` -- I doubt this is what's needed -- or change the resistor network such that the DC operating point changes. Since this is an assignment, I'll leave that up to you. Is `C1` meant to be tied to ground, or was there supposed to be a load afterwards? I ask because your source is modelled as a sine.

Comment: to vary the DC Bias point , I have varied R1 from 1k to 1000k in steps of 1k. Then did the AC analysis at 1kHZ. However , the option to change "R1" is greyed out . Yeah , C1 is meant to be tied to the ground.

Comment: Yes , I have removed V3  , and the circuit is same as the first image except that I have varied R1 and removed "Iin"

Comment: Do you need to find out the **DC** characteristics, or a **frequency** analysis? Think well, because for the 1st you don't need any `SINE()` input or capacitors and an `.OP` simulation is what you're looking for, and for the second you'd need a load after `C1`, yet you say it needs to be tied to ground (i.e. it shorts out `RE` at high frequencies) I don;t understand what you mean by "R1 is greyed out".